# How to verify if the Analytics 360 is successfully linked with BigQuery or not?

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to integrate Google Analytics 360 with BigQuery. However, despite following the due [procedure](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en-IN&utm_id=ad), I am unable to link these two.

After completing all the procedure and even waiting for 24 hours, what I am getting in BigQuery is just the name of the DataSet without any data or table.

I expect to see in BigQuery the two datasets, ga_sessions and ga_sessions_intraday.

> Note: The option to click on **Link BigQuery** in Analytics 360 (->
>   property -> All Products -> BigQuery) was not available.

Comment: Are you sure billing is enabled on your project? Can you provide a screenshot showing the steps you have done?

Comment: Yes, billing is enabled. [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tTxX5yzGMsVCiriABE4Yw3Yg4zp-_2f3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Maybe OP will be able to help but I feel your best course or action is to contact Google support directly on this type of issue

Comment: If the option "Link BigQuery" was not available, then how did you do follow the instructions? If this is not available then you won't be able to link GA and BQ. Did you check that the relevant property has already been added to your GA360 contract? Also the dataset will have the name of a view you are exporting. ga_sessions and ga_sessions_intraday are sets of tables within the dataset (each table will have a date suffix).

Comment: @EikePierstorff there is an option in bigQuery to **Create Dataset** where I entered the project number and it created the dataset (but it's blank). If I try to create a **Table** inside it, couldn't find any relevant option. And to answer, how did I follow the instructions, please have a look at [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cFBt3EYD2obT4XDzg0RBzTWeYCxrxkx1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The usual procedure is that you enter your project id in the GA property settings, and it will then create a dataset in BQ (with a viewid as name) automatically and backfill with the data from the last 13 months. I don't think any other way will work. Your Google Drive link is not public.

Comment: @EikePierstorff [Updated Link for the image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BuX4zTU52fZpwUJlm9sqL1DBIMZti2qj/view?usp=sharing) Please have a look at it.

Comment: There should be a button. You cannot create the integration in BigQuery itself, this has to be done within the GA property settings. If you have verified that you have the necessary permissions in GA and you still don't see the "Link BigQuery" button you need to contact your Google support (included in GA360, so no extra cost, although they are not obliged to help with BQ beyond setting up the link).